# What is the best way to compare two string arrays without indexing through each element?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, string-comparison

Is there any efficient way that can be used to compare two string arrays without checking through each element?

I tried using Array Lists, building objects, but none of them didn't show much effect.

Comment: should they be completely identical? or is it enough if 1 array contains the other?

Comment: what do you want to compare? if each element which arrays keep the same? or arrays the same (refer to one object in memory)?

Comment: If you want to compare String arrays, that means you want to compare String objects that are forming arrays. So at some point you will hit to String elements. Even you use a library, it will also, and have to, evaluate String elements.

Comment: If you use list then complexity will be O(N*N).You can create one set and then check contains.If you want to check whole array is equal or not then you can calculate some kind of hash function and check.

Answer (score 10):

In the end, to compare two "sequences" of Strings (which represent sequences of characters), there is no magic trick for efficiency.

You have to *somehow* walk through both sequences and compare them element by element.

In that sense, the only thing you can strive for is: "efficient" coding style; in other words: focus on writing human readable code.

And then of course, the existing library call Arrays.equals() would be your first stop. Beyond that: you can be pretty sure that whatever you can  write down yourself will **not** perform "better" than the standard built-in solution.

Beyond that: keep in mind that there is a difference between deciding: do two equally sized arrays have the same elements; or do they have the **exact same** order of elements on top of that?

In other words; *you* have to clarify if [A, B] is equal to [B, A] - to decide if  [Array.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) with

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)). In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

is really what you need!

If the order is **not** important to you, you would first have to **sort** both arrays - as that puts both array content into the same order.

Final thought: performance wise, there shouldn't be (much) difference between using arrays and ArrayList here. And in the context of my answer, we simply find that you can compare to lists even more easily by putting down `listA.equals(listB)` (which will give you the Arrays.equals() semantics).

The only aspect that might really affect performance is: when your use case would allow for using sets ...

Comment: The only valid answer. All other answers are "hiding" the traversal of all elements by a higher order API

Comment: How it will work if the array is not sorted and if of different length .Question is compare it will return 0 if equal and 1 and -1 respectively

Comment: @gatisahu Good point. I enhanced my answer; hopefully this more clear now.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning (as an aside) that the above is only strictly true if you compare two arrays in isolation. If you've got many arrays that you need to compare pairwise with each other, or just many that you need to compare to the same fixed one, you can do better than do all the pairwise comparisons in full.

Comment: @biziclop Its funny, it sounds like such a "simple" problem; but one could spent hours thinking about this.

Comment: @GhostCat Hours? I bet you can get a complete PhD thesis out of it if you try hard enough. :)

Comment: it was so helpful :)

Comment: @M3trix You are very welcome. Always nice to find old content being still helpful!

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for exact match for comparing two arrays, you can use `Arrays` `equals()` method from JDK like [Arrays.equals(array1, array2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-) as shown below:

**Code Sample:**

```
String[] a1 = {"A", "B"};
String[] a2 = {"A", "B"};
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a1, a2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
```

But, as @GhostCat suggested, there is no magic that happens here i.e., **the iteration and comparisons of strings happen inside the `Arrays.equals()` method** and then returns the `true` or `false`.

Also, note that, in the above example, for the case like `a2={"B","A"}`, the `equals()` returns `false`.

Comment: Might work or might not: depends on exactly what OP meant by "comparing string arrays".

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Good point; gave me another thought for my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "compare," `StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance()` and `StringUtils.getFuzzyDistance()` in Apache Commons Lang may help.  More info [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html).